# Python "int64" cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb

In my company we have a MongoDB collection with some information about power sources. I'm trying to do a python scritp to take that information and put it into a MySQL DB.

The problem is that I'm getting an error while loading the data to MySQL. This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\ngabioud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packag
>   es\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 179, in to_mysql
>       return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value) AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute
>   '_int64_to_mysql'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\ngabioud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packag
>   es\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 417, in _process_params
>       res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]   File "C:\Users\ngabioud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packag
>   es\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 417, in 
>       res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]   File "C:\Users\ngabioud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packag
>   es\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 182, in to_mysql
>       "MySQL type".format(type_name)) TypeError: Python 'int64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Fuentes y tickets ME.py",
>   line 114, in 
>       mycursor.execute(querysql, queryval)   File "C:\Users\ngabioud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packag
>   es\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 539, in execute
>       psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))   File "C:\Users\ngabioud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packag
>   es\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 422, in _process_params
>       "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing
>   format-parameters; Py thon 'int64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Then, this is the python code:

```
idFuente = x['idFuente']   #Tried      np.int64(x['idFuente'])    but still not working
direccion = x['direccion']['calle'] + " " + str(x['direccion']['nro'])
nodoUbicacion = x['direccion']['nodoUbic']
nodoAlimenta = x['nodoAlimenta']
tieneTransponder = x['tieneTransponder']
tuvoTransponder = x['tuvoTransponder']
macTp = x['macTp']
tieneBaterias = x['tieneBaterias']
tuvoBaterias = x['tuvoBaterias']

try:
    tp_psBatteriesPerString = x['info_poleo']['tp_psBatteriesPerString']
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_1 = x['info_poleo']['tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_1']
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_2 = x['info_poleo']['tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_2']
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_3 = x['info_poleo']['tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_3']
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_1 = x['info_poleo']['tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_1']
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_2 = x['info_poleo']['tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_2']
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_3 = x['info_poleo']['tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_3']
    tp_psTotalStringVoltage = ['info_poleo']['tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_3']
except:
    tp_psBatteriesPerString = None
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_1 = None
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_2 = None
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_3 = None
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_1 = None
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_2 = None
    tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_3 = None
    tp_psTotalStringVoltage = None

querysql = "INSERT INTO fuentes (`idFuente`, `direccion`, `nodoUbicacion`, `nodoAlimenta`, `tieneTransponder`, `tuvoTransponder`, `macTp`, `tieneBaterias`, `tuvoBaterias`, `tp_psBatteriesPerString`, `tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_1`, `tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_2`, `tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_3`, `tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_1`, `tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_2`, `tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_3`, `tp_psTotalStringVoltage`, `fechaCarga`) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"  
queryval= (idFuente, direccion,nodoUbicacion,nodoAlimenta,tieneTransponder,tuvoTransponder, macTp, tieneBaterias, tuvoBaterias, tp_psBatteriesPerString, tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_1,tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_2,tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_1_Battery_3,tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_1,tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_2,tp_psBatteryVoltage_String_2_Battery_3,tp_psTotalStringVoltage,fechaCarga)   
mycursor.execute(querysql, queryval)
```

This is the MySQL table structure:

[image]

And this is an example from the MongoDB result:

[image]

Where am I failing at? Do I have to make a conversion of the data type? How can I do it? I'm using pymongo and mysql.connector

Thanks!

Comment: can you print value queryval ?..and add it here

Comment: you can try `idFuente = int(x['idFuente'])`

Comment: We need to see how you are getting the data out of mongodb; i.e. how is `x` populated?

Comment: Thanks all for your help. @DDhaliwal suggestion worked :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did what @DDhaliwal suggested and it worked.

```py
idFuente = int(x['idFuente'])
```

Thanks!